# Manipulating XML in Gradle/Groovy with new 'file' node

Tags: xml, gradle, groovy, xmlslurper

I am trying to manipulate a wildfly 10.1. `standalone.xml` via gradle buildscript to modify logger settings. I have done this before, and with logger entries, this works as expected. However, now I need to add a new `periodic-rotating-file-handler` which in itself is not a problem, but it does act up when trying to tell what file to actually log to.

Existing code:

```scala
def configFile = {wildflyDir}/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml"
def xml = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parse(configFile)
def logging = xml.profile.subsystem.find{ it['@xmlns'] == "urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0' }
logging.appendNode {
    logger(category:"loggingCategory") {
        level(name:"LEVEL")
    }
}
```

This is, as expected, highly functional. Now I need to add a snippet like this:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN" />
    </formatter>
    <file path="file.log" relative-to="jboss.logging.dir" />
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <append value="true" />
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

The problem exists in the `file` definition, as that one would look like this in the `build.gradle` file:

```
file(path:"file.log" "relative-to":"jboss.logging.dir")
```

And this is being interpreted by gradle as `new File(arg1, arg2)`, so basically it is trying to add a file-Object with the given parameters to the XML.

This is valid, but definitely not what I want, since I just need the corresponding XML Node. I tried escaping in multiple ways:

- escaped `file` with single quotes, double quotes, triple quotes, made it a slashy and a dollarslashy string -> Tried to create a File object
- escaped the whole line with those same options -> line is not present in XML
- tried adding node without parentheses -> tried to create File object
- tried adding as extra closure -> tried to create File object
- tried extracting the node as text, parsing is with XMLSlurper and addind that to the XML -> snippet not present in XML

There have been a few more things I tried, but I cannot recall them due to frustration.

My final attempt was to try and just add an empty `file` node to the XML, however when using `file()` gradle did not know which File-constructor to use, and when I used `file` I got an error: `Namespace prefix: file is not bound to a URI`

If anyone has any idea how to properly escape `file` or has another way of adding said `file`-node to the XML please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the file with the Groovy XML Slurper, modify the structure, than save the modified XML to file?

Comment: I ended up using a workaround - I saved the snippet to a file, slurp and modify that and add the resulting node to the logging subsystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) call builder functions on delegate:**

```groovy
//just declare `file` to emulate problem in usual groovy console 
def file={String a, String b-> println "file: a=$a, b=$b"}

def xml = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText('''
    <root>
        <profile>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0"/>
        </profile>
    </root>''')

def logging = xml.profile.subsystem.find{ it['@xmlns'] == "urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0" }

logging.plus{
    logger(category:"loggingCategory") {
        level(name:"LEVEL")
    }
    //be specific that you want to call file function on delegate and not on owner (by default)
    delegate.'file'(path:"file.log", "relative-to":"jboss.logging.dir")
    //or this also works:
    "${'file'}"(path:"file.log", "relative-to":"jboss.logging.dir")

}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

**(2) workaround with XmlParser :**

use `current` as accessor to current parent node

```groovy
def xml = new XmlParser(false,false).parseText('''
    <root>
        <profile>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0"/>
        </profile>
    </root>''')

def logging = xml.profile.subsystem.find{ it['@xmlns'] == "urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0" }

logging.plus{
    logger(category:"loggingCategory") {
        level(name:"LEVEL")
    }
    current.appendNode("file", [path:"file.log", "relative-to":"jboss.logging.dir"])
}

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Comment: Thank you, the `delegate`.call worked perfectly. I am using another solution now (parse and modify prepared xml and add that to the main xml), but this helps for the next time this happens =)